# Check for camera permissions on real time on a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a camera view in my app and the problem is that when the app checks if there's camera permission it refreshes only when the user moves to a different activity and comes back and not real time:

```
class _BarcodeScannerViewState extends State<BarcodeScannerView> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final BarcodeScanner _barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanner();
  bool _canProcess = true;
  bool _isBusy = false;
  CustomPaint? _customPaint;
  String? _text;
  bool _hasNavigated = false;
  var _cameraLensDirection = CameraLensDirection.back;
  Future<PermissionStatus>? _cameraPermission;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cameraPermission = _checkAndRequestCameraPermission();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _canProcess = false;
    _barcodeScanner.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<PermissionStatus> _checkAndRequestCameraPermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.camera.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.camera.request();
    }
    return status;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _cameraPermission,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.data == PermissionStatus.granted) {
              return _buildCameraView();
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text('Camera permission not granted'),
                    SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => _checkAndRequestCameraPermission(),
                      child: Text('Request Camera Permission'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCameraView() {
    return DetectorView(
      title: 'Barcode Scanner',
      customPaint: _customPaint,
      text: _text,
      onImage: _checkAndProcessImage,
      initialCameraLensDirection: _cameraLensDirection,
      onCameraLensDirectionChanged: (value) => _cameraLensDirection = value,
    );
  }
```

for the detectorview I use: [https://github.com/flutter-ml/google_ml_kit_flutter/blob/master/packages/example/lib/vision_detector_views/detector_view.dart](https://github.com/flutter-ml/google_ml_kit_flutter/blob/master/packages/example/lib/vision_detector_views/camera_view.dart)
and for the camera view: [here](https://github.com/flutter-ml/google_ml_kit_flutter/blob/master/packages/example/lib/vision_detector_views/camera_view.dart)

How can I check for the permission realtime and update the ui based on it?